# SQL - convert int to double

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two `bit` type columns in my sql table, and the values in it are like,

```
FirstHalfLeave         SecondHalfLeave
 ------------           -------------
      0                      1
      1                      1
```

I need to sum these two fields to make it leave for a single day and I need to dislay the exact result`(3/2=1.5)`

I just converted these `bit` to `integer` like

```
sum(CAST(StaffAttendance.FirstHalfStatus as Integer) + 
             CAST(StaffAttendance.SecondHalfStatus as integer))/2 as TotalLeave
```

it showing the result as `1` not `1.5`, for this I think I need to cast it to double or to float, I dunno how to do this, can anyone help me here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use `/2.0` instead to force decimal type

### Edit:

To remove the trailing zeros cast to `float`. And I think you placed a `)` wrong. Try:

```
select cast(
           sum(
                 (
                   CAST(StaffAttendance.FirstHalfStatus as Integer) + 
                   CAST(StaffAttendance.SecondHalfStatus as integer)
                 ) 
                 / 2.0
           ) as float
       ) as TotalLeave
from your_table
```

Comment: its not sum the value am getting the result like 0.5000000 and 1.000000 as two lines, how to truncate the decimal places and where am committing mistake for summin values?

Comment: when I multiply with 0.5 am getting the values correctly, and in the group by am using these two column names like StaffAttendance.FirstHalfstatus and StaffAttendance.SecondHalfStatus

Comment: @Shanish: See my update. Here is an example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7662/6)

Comment: @juergend: as I said, the fields are bit type, so its showing error like "Operand data type bit is invalid for add operator."

Comment: @juergend: also I have a field called "Date", I need to sum the values only for this month(am using this in my where condition like Month(GetDate()))"

Comment: @Shanish: Your welcome. I just updated the [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ce57/3) for completion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11427/discussion-between-shanish-and-juergen-d)

Comment: Sorry to ask this, I have one more doubt here, I have two more fields called "FirstHalfRemark" and "SecondHalfRemark", is it possible to group by these fields

Comment: @Shanish: Since you are using MSSQL it might not be that easy. I suggest asking another question and explain in detail what you want to achive.

Comment: thanks juergen, I just included the FirstHalfRemark and group by it, its working, since I have only two options in remark, they are Medical leave and Paid leave, thats it, thanks again for ur kind response

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to convert to double is multiplying by 1.0 like this:

```
   1.0 * (sum(CAST(StaffAttendance.FirstHalfStatus as Integer) + 
         CAST(StaffAttendance.SecondHalfStatus as integer)))/2 as TotalLeave
```

Answer (score 3):

Either divide by `2.0` or multiply to `0.5`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried casting the bit colums and floats instead of ints?

```
sum(CAST(StaffAttendance.FirstHalfStatus as float) + 
             CAST(StaffAttendance.SecondHalfStatus as float))/2 as TotalLeave
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 Sum(Case Cast(FirstHalfLeave + SecondHalfLeave as Numeric)) / Count(*)
```